# Вложенный SQL запрос DISTINCT и ORDER BY

Tags: sql

```
    SELECT DISTINCT  serverId FROM MatchesList WHERE Id in 
(SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT matchId FROM MatchesPlayers WHERE name='Player0') ORDER BY COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY serverId) DESC, serverId
```

Такой запрос. Есть таблица MatchesPlayers где я хочу выбрать все записи matchId. Затем я хочу выбрать все serverId из MatchesList чтобы у меня был лист уникальных serverId отсортированных по их количеству. Все бы хорошо, но ошибка

```
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все немного проще, оконные функции и distinct ни к чему, обычный group by делает то же самое:

```
SELECT serverId
  FROM MatchesList
 WHERE Id in 
   (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT matchId FROM MatchesPlayers WHERE name='Player0')
 GROUP BY serverId
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, serverId
```